# Synchronize SQL Server databases, getting delta for update

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization

Lots of questions about synchronizing databases, yet I have not found solution I like.

What I have: I have `master` SQL Server database, enterprise edition server, don't know schema in advance.

What I need: create `slave`/`replica` database and then based. Preserve all constrains, keys, triggers and so on. Grab delta of `inserted`/`deleted` data in `master` db. No need to track updates. Insert this delta in `replica` db.

What I found:

1. Microsoft Sync Framework. Would be best choice, but it modifies schema of `master` db. Adds tracking columns, triggers and so on. I can not modify schema of `master` db.
2. ApexSQL Diff and so on. Cons: they cost money, I need build in functionality as dll or executable. It must work out of box.
3. Database Mirroring. Sync or async, it work in real time. I need to grab delta from time to time, on demand. Also it is a question of maintaining this thing.
4. Doing by hand, traversing tree of tables, trying to figure correct order for data inserting. Cons: I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

What I miss? Is there a solution/library/package to analyse schema and get newly inserted data without modifying `master` db's schema?

UPD

Transactional Replication: is implemented by the SQL Server Snapshot Agent, Log Reader Agent, and Distribution Agent. It's the main cons, I need to do it from code. No additional access to SQL Server itself. (I might not have access to some more features that read)

Merge replication:  adds the column rowguid to every table, unless the table already has a column of data type uniqueidentifier with the ROWGUIDCOL property. I cannot modify existing schema, if I could I would stay on Sync Framework.

Restore transaction log: I can not guarantee that I have any log file. DB is not mine, I don't know schema.

Comment: Can you just restore transaction log backups from the master database onto the replica for your point in time change?

Comment: What happened to SQL Server integrated replication? Any reason you miss it?